# C++ header files simple question

Tags: c++, scope, header-files

Can .h files see what's in each other without being included? I know when I programmed in C before I could use variables in a .h file from other .h files without #include "myfile.h". I'm trying to do the same in C++ and I keep getting "definition out of scope error"

Comment: You can redeclare the variables needed as `extern` to prevent that error, but I don't think thats what your going for

Comment: Read this: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/19-header-files/

Answer (score 2):

Not directly.  However if the `.cc` or `.c` file `#include`s a file, then any headers `#include`d after it *will* see the contents of that header.  The reason is that `#include` behaves like a copy-and-paste: each files contents are effectively dumped together into one big file, and the compiler only sees the combined result.  For example if you have:

foo.cc:

```
#include <a.h>
#include <b.h>
#include <c.h>

// foo.cc's contents
```

Even though `b.h` doesn't `#include a.h`, its definitions will *still be visible* in b.h, because the compiler is seeing the contents of all the headers as if they were part of `foo.cc`.  This can be fairly problematic in practice as programs depend on definitions they aren't explicitly including.  When someone changes `a.h` you can start seeing errors in `b.h` (or at any header `#include`d afterwards).

But I don't think this completely answers your question, because this process alone shouldn't result in any "definition out of scope" errors.  Care to post a code sample that has the problem?

Comment: A little? `#include` is *exactly* a copy-and-paste, right down to whether or not there's a terminating newline on the last line of the included file.

Comment: @R. Pate: Yeah, but it also does things like add in #line directives so the compiler knows the file and line it's supposed to be on.  But I agree that it's important to emphasize the copy and paste part.  I'll edit.

Comment: @R.Pate: funny you should use that example. In C++, the behavior of a program is undefined if any non-empty source file doesn't have a terminating newline (2.1/1/2). The definition of "source file" encompasses what's usually called "header files". So that's the one aspect where it isn't necessarily equivalent to a copy-and-paste. I imagine all or nearly all preprocessors implement it that way, though. GCC warns if the newline is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Variables in a .h file are a precarious situation, because when you `#include` a header file it's just pasted into your source file. So if you have `int j;` in a header file and include it from other source files, you've basically just defined several different variables called `j`, which is, of course, an error.

Answer (score 0):

No, neither in C or C++.  It often happens that headers are included indirectly which is what may have occurred in your prior experience.

Answer (score 0):

In both C and C++ nothing is visible unless it is loaded into the compiled unit (the .c or .cpp file normally), or if it is explicitly declared.

You can forward declare a variable with "extern"

```
extern int somewhere_else; // now the somewhere_else defined elsewhere can be seen here
```

Older C compilers may have been more lenient on the need for forward declaring.